# Broadcast retrieved results from DB with accessors to socket.io or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, socket.io, accessor

**Problem:** I cannot retrieve an accessor argument in javascript file in Laravel 5.4

Scenario:

1. Get data
2. Modify retrieved data with [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)
3. Via Event broadcast to Listeners
4. Catch a broadcasted event in javascript with socket.io

In `App/SomeModel.php` I am doing a manipulation over retrieved data by using Eloquent.

Based on priority number, I assign a correct class name for bootstrap styling.

```
/**
 * Gets corresponding class name based on priority level.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPriorityClassAttribute(): string
{
    switch ($this->priority) {
        default:
            return '';
        case 1:
            return 'info';
        case 2:
            return 'success';
        case 3:
            return 'warning';
        case 4:
            return 'danger';
    }
}
```

Then I can access `$somedata->priority_class` everywhere across the application.

But I cannot pass those data to the Listeners in javascript. I don't know how should I add it to the data object.

Here is a `var_dump()` in my Event broadcaster:

```
#attributes: array:2 [
"priority" => 2
"id" => 128
```

]

Why there is no `priority_class` while it works if I want to `$somedata->priority_class` ?

Any tips ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! All I had to do, is to insert an attribute to `protected $appends` array;

```
/**
 * Append accessors to JSON response
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = [
    'priority_class'
];
```